# Hausdorff dimension mathces Box-counting dimension

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, reference-request, dimension-theory-analysis

I need to compute the Hausdorff dimension of certain sets using a computer and, to date, my approach has been to use a Box-counting algorithm, for I once read that the Hausdorff dimension of an auto-similar fractal set matches its Box-counting dimension. Now, my sets are not completely self-similar because they include a random factor on their construction, though the seed is always an auto-similar fractal set. Hence I was wondering if there is some wider class of sets for which both dimensions coincide. I tried proving such property for compact sets but I soon found a counter-example (namely the set $X=\left\{1/n, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \cup \left\{ 0 \right\}$). I thought that maybe connectedness may play a role, but to the point I haven't found any piece of literature regarding this or any similar facts.

So, any knowledge on the topic or known references would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Do not expect *topological* properties (compactness, connectedness, etc) to tell you much about *metric* properties (such as the Hausdorff dimension). To get an idea of how difficult the question of equality is, consider the following: the graph of Weierstrass function $y=\sum a^k \cos (2\pi b^k x)$ with $ab>1$, $a<1<b$, has been known to have Minkowski dimension $D=2+\frac{\log a}{\log b}$ since 1984. Its Hausdorff dimension is conjectured to also be equal to $D$, but this remains an open problem despite a large number of papers published on the subject.

One class of sets in which Minkowski and Hausdorff dimensions coincide is *Ahlfors regular sets* (also known as Ahlfors-David regular, or simply regular). These sets support a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(B)\approx (\operatorname{diam} B)^d$ for every ball $B$. The catch is:   if you can prove that a set is Ahlfors regular, then you already know its Hausdorff dimension, namely $d$.

Since you already know Minkowski dimension $d$, I think that your best bet is to look for a positive measure $\mu$ supported on the set   that has finite *energy* $\iint |x-y|^{-t}\,d\mu_x\,d\mu_y$ for   $t<d$. The existence of such a measure (for every $t<d$) implies that   the Hausdorff dimension is at least $d$. In 1998 Hunt used this approach to show that the graph of a random  Weierstrass-type function has the conjectured Hausdorff dimension $D=2+\frac{\log a}{\log b}$ with probability $1$. See *[The Hausdorff dimension of graphs of Weierstrass functions](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-03/S0002-9939-98-04387-1/)*. 
Heuristically speaking: for the Hausdorff and Minkowski dimensions to be different, the set must have infinitely many "abnormal" scales; and for a random set the probability of this happening is $0$. Of course, how true the preceding sentence is depends on the kind of randomness you have.

I also recommend the  recent paper *[On the dimension of the graph of the classical Weierstrass function](http://www.math.bme.hu/~balubs/cikkek/weierstrass.pdf)* by Baranski, Barany and Romanowska; it includes a survey of recent results, including ([1] and [7] in the paper) the non-equality of Minkowski and Hausdorff dimensions of the graph of a sparse-scale Weierstrass-type function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My sets are basically randomized versions of the Koch snowflake, the purpose being to simulate coastal profiles (I kow about Brownian motion-related methods, but I am focusing on this ones). The random component is just varying the angles and the lengths of the newly-formed triangles at every step of the process. The set itself can eb described as the attractor of a "randomized iterated function system", but the random variables used are basically uniform ones.

Comment: It may be of interest to add to following Baire category results. In the sense of Baire category, almost all compact sets in ${\mathbb R}^2$ (relative to the Hausdorff hyperspace metric) has Hausdorff dimension $0$ and box dimension $2.$ In the sense of Baire category, the graphs of almost all continuous functions $f:[0,1] \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ (relative to the sup norm) have Hausdorff dimension $1$ and box dimension $2.$ See Mauldin/Williams *On the Hausdorff dimension of some graphs* and Gruber *Dimension and structure of typical compact sets, continua and curves*.